# Removing the number of first page in Yii2 Pagination from the URL

Tags: .htaccess, pagination, seo, yii2

For SEO purposes I need to remove the first page number from the URL. i.e I have the following:

`example.com/pages/view/1` and `example.com/pages/view` the two URLs points to the same contents of the view action. I want to make the pagination free from `1` in the URL. i.e first Page link and Page Number 1 should be linked to `pages/view`.

I tried to deal with the $pagination object like the following:

```
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $books['booksCount'], 'pageParam' => 'start', 'defaultPageSize' => 10,]);
      $pagingLinks = $pages->getLinks();
      $pagingLinks['first'] = '/';
      $pages->links = $pagingLinks;
```

However, the last line causing error:

> **Setting read-only property: yii\data\Pagination::links**

So I have a problem to modify the links property. Is there any other solution to get this task done?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html#$forcePageParam-detail) you should set `yii\data\Pagination::forcePageParam` to false by passing it in Pagination constructor

```
$pages = new Pagination([
    'totalCount' => $books['booksCount'], 
    'pageParam' => 'start', 
    'defaultPageSize' => 10,
    'forcePageParam' => false,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer may works for direct use of `Pagination` but remain an issue if it was used from another widget such as ListView.

I found the solution from a [comment on an issue report](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/8564#issuecomment-105829860) on Yii2 repository on github

The solution is just define proper route in `config/web.php`. Suppose here we have a controller called `Suras` and we use the `ListView` widget on its action's view called `view`. So placing rule array with `defaults` has value `'page' => 1` will prevent adding the `page` parameter to the link's URL of the first page. Also notice the first rule `'view/<id:\d+>/1' => 'Error404',` is placed in-order to prevent any access to the first page using `page=1` parameter, for example, trying to access `mysite.com/view/20/1` will invoke 404 error, because there is no controller called `Error404`.

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [                
                'view/<id:\d+>/1' => 'Error404',
                ['pattern' => 'view/<id:\d+>/<page:\d+>', 'route' => 'suras/view', 'defaults' => ['page' => 1]],
                'view/<id:\d+>/<page:\d+>' => 'suras/view',
                'view/<id:\d+>' => 'suras/view',
            ],
        ],


],
```